# How to change the Front page for the Commerce Kickstart distribution?

Tags: commerce

Just that. I changed the front page to "my-front-page". Now if I go to the front page the fields for this node aren't shown at all. Just the blocks are shown.

I guess there is a preprocess function related to the front page. The only one that I see is this one, but nothing happens if I delete this function:

```
function commerce_kickstart_theme_alpha_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_front']) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['content']['content']['system_main']);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the fields for this node aren't shown at all" ??

Comment: The node I set as <front> is a 'basic page content type' node. This content type has a 'body field'. In this body field I put some text. When viewing the front page the 'body field' is not shown. I already checked 'manage display' for this content type and the body field is enabled.

Comment: I think it must be a preprocess function or a template file, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this preprocess function needs to be changed in the parent theme.

In this case it can be found in the `/profiles/commerce_kickstart/themes/omega_kickstart/preprocess` folder.

Comment: Yes, I get the same answer in the issue I posted for the distribution.