# How do I change the front page?

Tags: commerce

In commerce guys demos store I toggled off the main menu in commerce kickstart template and have enabled the main menu block to stay on sidebar first block. I want to get a vertical main menu instead of a horizontal one like the demo store default installation.

Besides, I disabled the slide show content. I want to get the products of a specific collection to be displayed in front page. So I went to Site settings > configuration > System information and changed the default front page URL to collection/my-collection.

But the page doesn't display the main menu on sidebar first. The my-collection colletion is displayed but lose that tiny margins that wrap the products.

I follow this [drupal.stackexchange post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46058/how-to-change-the-front-page-for-the-commerce-kickstart-distribution) and tried to comment out the lines

```
function omega_kickstart_alpha_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_front']) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['content']['content']['system_main']['default_message']);
  }
}
```

in both profiles/omega_kickstart/preprocess/preprocess-page.inc and profiles/commerce_kickstart/preprocess/preprocess-page.inc, but didn't work.

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the block configuration for the menu, might be set to only on the default front page, changing the default home page changes the url, so your block needs to be configure to display on the url for your "new" front page. At least I think this is what's going on.

Comment: i.e. it's probably set to <front>